# Strange user name in the login list

Tags: users, user-management

On one of my servers on this is login prompt:

[image]

I've surprisingly found one more user in the list (not available on this sample picture from the internet) with name "**\**". I don't see such a user in /home folder. I don't remember myself adding this user to the system. What might this be? What can I do to remove it?

Comment: Can you let us know which Ubuntu version are you using ?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how he got there but to remove him you just need to become root and then run this command:

```
userdel [The username here]
```

Note that the username might not be **John Smith**, instead try to get his username using this command to view the file that contains the passwords:

```
cat /etc/passwd
```

The username will be on the left.

Comment: Still, it might be useful to know how and when this ghost user was added. You may want to look at the modification timestamp of `/etc/passwd` and `/etc/group`. See if this user has logged in (`last [username]`) and from which IP address. In `/etc/passwd` find out if this user has a working login directory or not.